# C++ Self Installable Windows Service

Tags: c++, windows, windows-services

Is it possible to Create such creature in C++ ? I know in Managed C# is absolutely doable , there was Installer helper class that allows to this.

The question is if it's possible to achieve such functionality in VC++ ?

Thanks.

Comment: .NET doesn't magically add any OS feature. Anything you can do in .NET you can do in C. Services are documented in the MSDN: [About Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681921.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

For those who are looking for the same 
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppWindowsService-cacf4948